# Gamma, Theta, Vega, Vanna and Volga PnL under Bachelier

Tags: volatility, gamma, vega, bachelier

Is there a PDE that decomposes the daily PnL as delta, gamma, vega vanna and volga but under Bachelier model (assuming normal vol) ?

Comment: It's no different than the Black Scholes case, except the Greeks are now Bachelier Greeks.

Comment: See also the following thread: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/53392/is-there-anywhere-i-can-read-the-paper-the-gamma-vanna-volga-cost-framework-fo